# Swift FileManger doesn't include contents when copying directory from 'Files' app long-press-copy

Tags: ios, swift, directory, nsfilemanager

In the 'Files' app, I can import a file or a directory of files into my app by using the 'Select' option and then choosing the directory/file and then using the share button, select my app.  The app then opens and runs my `importURL` function and all works well.  (Part of this relies on having correct UTIs, etc).

However, if in the 'Files' app, I perform a long-press on a folder and then 'Copy' that folder.  Then I switch back to my app and do a paste which runs the exact same code, it merely copies the folder with none of the files in it.

Is there any way to get this copy/import to work from a 'Files' app 'Copy'?

No errors are reported in XCode or in the app when it occurs.

```swift
        coordinator.coordinate(readingItemAt: url, options: .withoutChanges, error: &err) { (coordinatedURL) in
            do {
                try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: url, to: AppDelegate.docsDir.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent))
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.refreshData()
                }
            } catch {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Cannot Copy Data Source", message: "Unable to copy from:\n\(url)\n\nError details:\n\n\(error)", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                    self.present(alert, animated: true)
                }
            }
        }
        if isSecure {
            url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
        }
```

When the problem occurs, I'm getting the URL from the pasteboard like this:

```swift
            guard let itemType = UIPasteboard.general.types.first else { return }
            guard let pasteItemProvider = UIPasteboard.general.itemProviders.first else { return }
                pasteItemProvider.loadInPlaceFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: itemType) { (url, ok, err) in
                    if url != nil {
                        self.importFromURL(url!)
                    } else if err != nil {
                        print("FAILED to load file by item provider's URL.  Error:\n\(err!)")
                    }
                }
            }
```

**UPDATE:  Sometimes occurs when using the select method also!**

I've found that this problem sometimes occurs with the 'Select' method described above as being the work-around that normally works.  Well it turns out that it doesn't work reliably either.

**What DOES work reliably (so far):**

...is copying the folder entirely within the 'Files' app.  Ie, Select, then tap the folder icon (bottom toolbar) then (still in the 'Files' app), selecting the 'On My iPhone' item and then selecting the custom app's folder there.

This seems to work reliably so far.  But using the NSFileCoodinator.coordinate() and the FileManager.copyItem() does NOT reliably copy a folders contents from the 'Files' app.